# How to call C# method in jQuery?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I am using a chart which should get Input from C# for plotting the graph. I am using JSON for returning the values from C# to jQuery. Anyhow it doesn't help me, what did I do wrong?

This is my aspx code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var source = {};

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "Default.aspx/getall",
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {

                source = $.parseJSON(response.d);

            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
</script>
```

And this is my C# code:

```cs
public class sampledata
{
    public string Day { get; set; }
    public int Keith { get; set; }
    public int Erica { get; set; }
    public int George { get; set; }
}

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    List<sampledata> s = new List<sampledata>();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        s.Add(new sampledata { Day = "monday", Keith = 20, Erica = 15, George = 25 });
        s.Add(new sampledata { Day = "tuesday", Keith = 25, Erica = 20, George = 35 });

        Session["data"] = s;                  
    }

    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static List<sampledata> getall()
    {
        List<sampledata> data = (List<sampledata>)HttpContext.Current.Session["data"];
        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `console.log(response)` in success?

Comment: I think you are calling this method as a webservice. you need to add web service to call getall

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested your code and everything seems to be fine, except that I serialized the List into a string and returned.

```js
$(window).load(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "PageMethodTest.aspx/getall",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: fnsuccesscallback,
        error: fnerrorcallback
    });
});

function btnclick() {}

function fnsuccesscallback(data) {
    alert(data.d);

}

function fnerrorcallback(result) {
    alert(result.statusText);
}
```

Server side code:

```cs
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static String getall()
{
    List<sampledata> data = (List<sampledata>)HttpContext.Current.Session["data"];
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    return js.Serialize(data);
    //return data;
}
```

And the result is:

[image]

You can improve on using the output as source for your graph.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of ajax postback, you can use PageMethods:

In C# page:

```cs
[WebMethod]
public static List<sampledata> getall()
{
    List<sampledata> data = (List<sampledata>)HttpContext.Current.Session["data"];
    return data;
}
```

In the aspx page:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data=PageMethods.getall(OnSuccess);

    function OnSuccess() {
        alert("Success");
    }
});
```

And for using PageMethods you also need to add this in your form tag:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to rely on Microsoft's AJAX implementation (the `WebMethodAttribute`, `ScriptManager`, having to worry about that `.d` property of the response, etc.), you can do nice clean JSON calls using ASHX handlers. You have to do a little bit of work yourself, but you get out from under WebForms's thumb a bit by doing more traditional AJAX.

For your example, the C# piece would be as follows (note the `IRequiresSessionState` implementation, which makes your session available):

```
// something.ashx.cs
public class something : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState {
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(context.Session["data"]));
    }

    public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }
}
```

Your javascript call would just be a call to this `something.ashx` file:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "something.ashx",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json"
}).done(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

You don't have any POST parameters, but if you did, you'd just have to include them in your call, and read them directly from the `Request` in your handler:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    ...
    data: { requestMessage: "Hello!" }
});


public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
    string requestMessage = context.Request["requestMessage"]; // Hello!
    ...etc...
}
```

Comment: Quick question, I am trying to understand it and not able to figure out what is being returned in `.done(function(result))`'s `result` variable.

Comment: @CodeIt The `done` function's parameter is a function which contains the result of the AJAX call, in the type that you asked for. In this example, the `dataType` field is set to `json`, which means that jQuery will be smart enough to look at the result from the server, which is in JSON format, and it will convert it to the object that the JSON represents. For example, if your server sends `{"name":"John"}`, then `result` will actually be a javascript object `{name: "John"}`. [See the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for lots of ways to use jQuery AJAX.

Comment: Good explanation @Joe Enos. And how the server is supposed to send a `json` response? I actually found this answer unique and neat, so I am trying to dig deep in it. sorry if I am being nerd.

Comment: @CodeIt The server can build the JSON however it wants. In my example in this answer, it's using the `JsonConvert.SerializeObject` method, which is part of the JSON.NET library, the most common JSON library in .NET, and then it writes the JSON and the content type directly to the response. ASP.NET MVC has a built-in method (the `Json` method) to write JSON to the response. Other server frameworks will have their own way of doing it - you'd have to look at the docs for PHP or Rails or whatever else, to figure out the best way to do it.