# how to call a method in aspx.cs through $.ajax jquery in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

this is the aspx.cs page i want to hit the callme() method through ajax call

```
public void callme()
            {
                if (ddlApprovalType.SelectedValue == "1") // location
                {
                    BindDropdownlist(ddlLocation, "LOC");// LOC = Location
                }
                else if (ddlApprovalType.SelectedValue == "2") // process
                {
                    BindDropdownlist(ddlLocation, "LOC");// LOC = Location
                    ddlProcess.Items.Clear();
                    ddlSubProcess.Items.Clear();
                    ddlProcess.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem()
                    {
                        Value = "select",
                        Text = "---Select---",
                        Selected = true
                    });
                    ddlSubProcess.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem()
                    {
                        Value = "select",
                        Text = "---Select---",
                        Selected = true
                    });
                }

            }
```

this is my .aspx page

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlApprovalType" AutoPostBack="True" class="clsapprovalType" Style="font-family: arial;
                                    font-size: 13px; color: #353535; width: 200px; border: solid 1px #353535; background-color: transparent;" />



  <script type="text/javascript">
              $(".clsapprovalType").change(function () {
                  var approvalTypeVal = $j(this).val();
                  if (approvalTypeVal == "1") {
                      ("#trlocation").show();
                  }
               $.ajax({url:'mypage.aspx/callme', method:get});
              });
        </script>
```

how to hit callme() method through $.ajax in asp.net using jquery without using update panel?

Comment: Either setup an HttpHandler, or have a look at [WebMethods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: @Andrei: Eventhough OP uses a webmethod. Will it be possible to access server controls inside an Webmethod ?

Comment: @Suprabhat, of course not. Then OP will need to change the way response if used. But i see the point, update panel might be a better option here

Answer (score 0):

first thing you need to know ajax will make calls for only static methods. ultimately you cannot access page level controls in static method. so you have to pass parameters and return the o/p to client side and manipulate DOM at client side code i.e.., inside ajax success function.

for ajax calls it is already answered in many posts. You can go through this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19701658/how-to-call-c-sharp-method-in-jquery)